# Scrollview Padding One Side More than the Opposite Side (Python Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way in the kv language to pad one side of a scrollview widget more than its opposite?

Here's a runnable example...

**Python Code:**

```
from kivy.app import App
# kivy.require("1.10.0")
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    text = "blah blah blah"

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class BackHomeWidget(Widget):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("Test_Running_Console.kv")

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**Kv Code:**

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<SmallNavButton@Button>:    
    font_size: 32
    size: 125, 50    
    color: 0,1,0,1

<MedButton@Button>:
    font_size: 30
    size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
    color: 0,1,0,1

<BackHomeWidget>:
    SmallNavButton:
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        text: "Home"
        pos: root.x, root.top - self.height

<ScrollableLabel>:
    Label:
        id: dataentryinstructions
        text: root.text
        font_size: 20
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        padding_y: 10
        padding_x: 200

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout: 
        MedButton:
            on_release: app.root.current = "newgarage"
            text: "Create New"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3728, "top": 0.4}

<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "newgarage"
    ScrollableLabel:
    BackHomeWidget:
    FloatLayout:
        MedButton
            text: "1. Stuff"
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top": 0.75}
```

As one may guess from the look of it, this pads the left and right side at 200 and the top and bottom at 10. But what if I want to pad the left side at 200 and the right side at 120?

In this particular case, I just want the scrollview to take up the right half of the screen. (to avoid overlap with buttons)

Forgive me if I overlooked this in the Kivy documentation. From the documentation, it looked like Gridlayout & BoxLayout can accept four arguments for padding (one for each direction), but wasn't sure how to incorporate that into a scrollview use case.

Comment: You could explain me better, perhaps a graph indicating what you get and what you want to obtain, your code can not be reproduced since there are widgets that are not defined.

Comment: I have updated the question to provide runnable code. The desire to control padding independently on either side of scrollview text is hopefully apparent from this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the whole label in a BoxLayout and add empty widgets with the desired width.

```
 <ScrollableLabel>:
    Widget:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
    ScrollView:
        Label:
            id: dataentryinstructions
            text: root.text
            font_size: 20
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 10
    Widget:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 120
```

This is the whole code:

```
from kivy.app import App
# kivy.require("1.10.0")
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

class ScrollableLabel(BoxLayout):
    text = "blah blah blah"

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class BackHomeWidget(Widget):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_string("""
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<SmallNavButton@Button>:    
    font_size: 32
    size: 125, 50    
    color: 0,1,0,1

<MedButton@Button>:
    font_size: 30
    size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
    color: 0,1,0,1

<BackHomeWidget>:
    SmallNavButton:
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        text: "Home"
        pos: root.x, root.top - self.height

<ScrollableLabel>:
    Widget:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
    ScrollView:
        Label:
            id: dataentryinstructions
            text: root.text
            font_size: 20
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 10
    Widget:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 120


<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout: 
        MedButton:
            on_release: app.root.current = "newgarage"
            text: "Create New"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3728, "top": 0.4}

<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "newgarage"
    ScrollableLabel:
    BackHomeWidget:
    FloatLayout:
        MedButton
            text: "1. Stuff"
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top": 0.75}
""")

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```